# ErrorCode: 'AuthorizationPermissionMismatch'

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-data-lake-gen2, azure-storage-account

I have used service principal in Authentication type while creating Linked services.[image: service principal created]
but when i try to create a dataset in ADF (i am using adls) i am not able to see my file on container i am getting an error.
`ADLS Gen2 failed for forbidden: Storage operation '' on container 'raw-container' get failed with 'Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden''. Possible root causes: (1). It's possible because the service principal or managed identity don't have enough permission to access the data. (2). Please check storage network setting whether public network access is disabled. If disabled, use Managed Virtual Network IR and create Private Endpoint to access. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/managed-virtual-network-private-endpoint. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/tutorial-copy-data-portal-private (3). It's possible because some IP address ranges of Azure Data Factory are not allowed by your Azure Storage firewall settings. Azure Data Factory IP ranges please refer https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/azure-integration-runtime-ip-addresses. If you allow trusted Microsoft services to access this storage account option in firewall, you must use https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?tabs=data-factory#managed-identity. For more information on Azure Storage firewalls settings, see https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-network-security?tabs=azure-portal.. Account: 'storage1998acc'. FileSystem: 'raw-container'. ErrorCode: 'AuthorizationPermissionMismatch'. Message: 'This request is not authorized to perform this operation using this permission.'. RequestId: '04dc03d9-a01f-009f-1c85-6c9ead000000'. TimeStamp: 'Tue, 11 Apr 2023 14:52:57 GMT'.. Operation returned an invalid status code 'Forbidden' Activity ID: 500eff90-9056-4084-a7cb-428c38af0523`

[image]

can you please help me i have checked access on IAM , public network access is also enabled

Comment: can you please share the details on how exactly are you connecting using linked service (share screenshot)?

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce the same in my environment. I got the same error.

[image]

To resolve this issue. You need to `enable and allow all networks` in the storage account and also grant the `Storage blob contributor` role to the storage account.

If you already have enough permission still you getting the same error. Try to use a different authentication method. If you are using a service principal to authenticate with your storage account, Try to use a managed identity or Account key or SAS. This will eliminate your issues with the permissions. In my scenario, I am using the Account key as the Authentication type.

[image]